# What is the meaning of "beta"?

Tags: meaning

Can somebody please explain what "beta" means in the following sentence:

> Tsugi no mokutekichi wa beta da keredo, Shikago.

Comment: Could you provide a little more context for where you found this word *(where it appears... or if this word is written in katakana, etc.)*?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the following rendering: 次の目的地はべただけれど、シカゴ。

In this context I'd say that べた means cliche or typical. This is a group of tourists whose next destination is Chicago, which is described as べた because it's a common tourist spot.

Comment: yes, suisou, that's the right 'spelling'. the speaker was speaking about his admiration for the Chicago Bulls and also about traveling. So can I assume it means "My next destination is, what else, Chicago!" ?

Comment: @eru Interesting transition with the "cliché" idea to "what else"... it does seem to sound a bit more modern than using the actual word "clichéd" in the sentence, like this: *"It might sound a little clichéd, but my next destination is Chicago."*

Comment: @suisou and summea thankyou so much for all your most helpful responses. I learn japanese just by buying piles and piles of grammar books and dictionaries, so it might sound a little clichéd, but I sure can use all the helps I could find.